# Split generation of a Shared Object library (.so) file into two pass instead of one

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, xlc

I am trying to build a shared library `lib_test.so` from 'test.c' & `test.exp` files. This `lib_test.so` file will be used as a extension to another application.
The application doc specifies generation of tle `lib_test.so` file directly in a single pass by the following command:

```
`gcc -q64 -o lib_test.so test.c -bM:Sre -bE:test.exp -bnoentry`
```

But my requirement is to build the library in two passes:

1. Compile to generate `test.o` file using `gcc` command.
2. Link to generate the library `lib_test.so` using `ld` command.

I tried this as follows:

1. Executed compile step as follows: `gcc -q64  -c -o test.o test.c`.
2. Create `lib_test.so` as follows: `ld -bM:Sre  -bE:test.exp -bnoentry -o lib_test.so test.o`

But it is not generating a proper `lib_test.so` file.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-Bit with latest GCC

Can you please suggest the correct way to split the process into two passes...

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not generating a proper `lib_test.so` file"? Do you get build errors? Errors when loading the library? Something else? Please elaborate.

Comment: when I build `lib_test.so` in one pass I get the so file of 12619 Bytes size and the application loads this library fine, but on building using two passes the output `lib_test.so` file is of 11816 Bytes and the application displays `loading extension failed` for `lib_test.so` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big difference between linking with the GCC frontend program `gcc` and with the actual linker `ld` is that the GCC frontend adds a few libraries to be linked with. Most notably the GCC runtime library (`-lgcc_s` or `-lgcc`) and the actual standard C library (`-lc`).

When you invoke `ld` directly you do not tell it to link with those libraries.

There might also be other libraries and flags the GCC frontend passes to `ld` without your knowledge. For the "one pass" build, pass the flag `-v` to `gcc` for verbose output and see what arguments, flags and libraries it uses.

Answer (score 2):

You rarely ever want to use `ld` to perform the linking. The gcc frontend does the better job of setting the right flags etc. So, use `gcc`.

i.e. Instead of

```
ld -bM:Sre  -bE:test.exp -bnoentry -o lib_test.so test.o
```

do

```
gcc -bM:Sre  -bE:test.exp -bnoentry -o lib_test.so test.o
```

in your second step.

Comment: I donot have this privilege to run these commands manually while building the library. I have to place my code (i.e, `test.c` and `test.exp`) to a specified directory and add `CFLAGS=<pass 1>` and `LDFLAGS=<pass 2>` in the makefile and the application runs `gcc -c ${CFLAGS} -o ${OFILE} ${IFILE}` to compile & generate `test.o` and next runs `ld ${LDFLAGS} -o ${SOFILE} ${OFILE}`. All this is done internally and I just have to give correct flags with ``gcc` & `ld` to get the lib_`test.so` so I asked for two pass building.